# How to use match function to get the position of multiple values across columns

Tags: excel, match

I am working with a data set that, for the purpose of this question, has values of 0, 1 and -1. I want to run two separate match functions. I want to find all of the columns that contain 1s and then find all the columns that contain -1s. I want these results to be put next to each other in new cells, horizontally. I've been using the match function successfully, but only when there is only one occurrence of each number.

I've googled extensively, but I can only find cases where people are combining INDEX + MATCH (https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-multiple-matches-into-separate-columns).

```
 id   2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008 2009  2010  
  1      0     0     0     0     0    -1     0     0    1    0   
  2      0     0     0    -1     0     0     1     0    0    0     
  3      0     0     0    -1     0     0     0     1    0    0  
  4      0    -1     0     0     0     0     1     0    0    0   
  5      0     0     0     1     0     0    -1     1    0    0 

# Match function:

= MATCH(-1, B2:B11,0)
= MATCH(1, B2:B11,0)

# This would output, for example: 

 id   2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008 2009  2010  neg1.pos1 
  1      0     0     0     0     0    -1     0     0    1    0     6
1.pos1
  9

# But this doesn't work if there is more than one instance of -1 or 1, it just gives the index of the first column that contains either number.
```

I want:

```
 id   2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008 2009  2010  neg1.pos1 
5      0     0     0     1     0     0    -1     1    0    0      7
1.pos1 1.pos2
   4     8
```

As you can see, it doesn't matter to me what value is in the column, I just want the column number that a specific value is in. I want to do this if there are multiple values per row.

Please let me know if there is a formula that can do this, and if I'm even on the right track with making the MATCH function work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be opposed to using VBA? I'm not sure of a way to visualize all values within an array formula, but I can think of a way to loop through each row and create an array to populate with each column #.

I'm making a few assumptions:

the column "id" is in column A

the headers are in row 1

There will be variable # of rows

There will not be variable # of columns

```
Sub ColCheck()

Dim ColNum, rCount, i As Long
Dim OneArray, TwoArray As Variant

rCount = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

Do While i <= rCount

OneArray = ""
TwoArray = ""

For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("B" & i & ":K" & i)
    If cell.Value = -1 And OneArray = "" Then
        OneArray = cell.Column
    ElseIf cell.Value = -1 And OneArray <> "" Then
        OneArray = OneArray & ", " & cell.Column
    End If
Next


For Each cell In Sheet2.Range("B" & i & ":K" & i)
    If cell.Value = 1 And TwoArray = "" Then
        TwoArray = cell.Column
    ElseIf cell.Value = 1 And TwoArray <> "" Then
        TwoArray = TwoArray & ", " & cell.Column
    End If
Next

If OneArray = "" Then OneArray = "No value found"
If TwoArray = "" Then TwoArray = "No value found"

With Sheet2
    .Range("M1").Value = "-1 Position"
    .Range("M" & i).Value = OneArray
    .Range("N1").Value = "1 Position"
    .Range("N" & i).Value = TwoArray
End With

i = i + 1


Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly! Not entirely familiar with VBA, so I may be misunderstanding what some of your code does. Question:

When you have:

[With Sheet2
    .Range("M1").Value = "-1 Position"
    .Range("M" & i).Value = OneArray
    .Range("N1").Value = "1 Position"
    .Range("N" & i).Value = TwoArray]
It looks like this is meant to add to another column, which would be ideal. Instead, it's comma separating these values within the same cell. This isn't the worst case, and I can work with this, but is there a way I can alter this code to instead add new cells?

Comment: Actually, it's fine, I think I'll just manually comma delimit the results! You're a lifesaver! Thank you so much!